# Get direction between two 3d vectors using Three.js?

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I have two points:

```
v1 = (0, 0, 0);
v2 = (10, 4, -3);
```

I want to get the direction between these two points so I can rayCast from point v1 to v2.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The pattern to follow to create a direction vector from `v1` to `v2` is this:

```
var dir = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once an reuse it

...

dir.subVectors( v2, v1 ).normalize();
```

Direction vectors in three.js are assumed to have unit-length. In other words, they must be normalized. If the direction vector you use when raycasting does not have length equal to 1, you will not get accurate results.

three.js r.82

Answer (score 6):

A little bit of math : direction = v2 - v1

Plus, a little bit of ThreeJS of documentation : https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3

Aannd ... Paf ! Solution !

```
 var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
 direction.subVectors( v2, v1 ) ;
```

Comment: Aha! It's that easy. Thanks I'll try this out.