# Three.js: Draw a vector on plane

Tags: three.js

I'm a newbie in three.js (and in stackoverflow).
I try to find answer but I'm not able to do this simple things.
I'm playing with Helpers and Plane.
I want to create a Plane (and it's PlaneHelper), and draw an arbitrary vector on this Plane.
All is right if the plane's distance from origin is set to 0.
If I give a distance to the plane, the vector is not on the plane.

Here is the commented code I use for this little experiment.
Projecting both the origin and the vector on the plane I was convinced that arrowHelper_Point remained on the plane, but it's not.
Where is my mistake? I can not understand it.

```
// Define ARROW_LENGTH to display ArrowHelper
const ARROW_LENGTH = 5;
// Point (0,0,0)
var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
// Axes helper in (0,0,0)
var axesHelperOrigin = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
scene.add(axesHelperOrigin);
// Define a plane by the normal, color and distance from (0,0,0)
var vectorNormal = {
    normal: new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0).normalize(),
    color: "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    colorNormal: "rgb(255,100,0)",
    colorVector: "rgb(194, 27, 255)",
    distance: -3,
};
// Create Plane from the normal and distance
var plane = new THREE.Plane(vectorNormal.normal, vectorNormal.distance);
// Add PlaneHelper to scene
var planeHelper = new THREE.PlaneHelper(plane, 100, vectorNormal.color);
scene.add(planeHelper);
// Add ArrowHelper to display normal
// Find the projection of origin on plane
var originOnPlane = plane.projectPoint(origin);
var arrowHelper_Normal = new THREE.ArrowHelper(vectorNormal.normal, originOnPlane, ARROW_LENGTH, vectorNormal.colorNormal);
scene.add(arrowHelper_Normal);
// Define a point "random"
var point = new THREE.Vector3(5, -2, 6);
// Project the point on plane
var pointOnPlane = plane.projectPoint(point);
// Draw ArrowHelper to display the pointOnPlane, from originOnPlane
var arrowHelper_Point = new THREE.ArrowHelper(pointOnPlane.normalize(), originOnPlane, ARROW_LENGTH, vectorNormal.colorVector);
scene.add(arrowHelper_Point);
```

EDIT: OK, I think I find the error.
Looking at this [Get direction between two 3d vectors using Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488945/get-direction-between-two-3d-vectors-using-three-js)

I need the vector between the two points:

```
var dir=new THREE.Vector3();
dir.subVectors(pointOnPlane,originOnPlane).normalize();
```

And use dir as the arrow direction.
Sorry for asking an obviously thing.

Comment: If you found an answer to you own question, you should write an answer and mark it as correct. This will help other people who stumbles over the same problem.

Comment: Thank you micnil for the info. I read the rules but I do the wrong thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [Get direction between two 3d vectors using Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488945/get-direction-between-two-3d-vectors-using-three-js)

I need the vector between the two points:

```
var dir=new THREE.Vector3();
dir.subVectors(pointOnPlane,originOnPlane).normalize();
```

And use dir as the arrow direction.